# How do I open files with extension ".vid" on MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

> How do I open files with extension ".vid" on MacBook?

I need help opening files with .vid extension? When selecting open with I am getting option to play it in

1. Photos
2. TV
3. Text Edit
4. Utilities

Why am I not getting option to play in Quick time player?

Comment: Use Videolan. It's free and open source software.

Comment: @146438 I can't find it on app store

Comment: Aye... if it was on the App Store, I woulda posted an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: is there any app available on App Store that will play .vid files?

Comment: if you could try Elmedia, let me know or post an answer yourself.

Comment: Just checked it, doesn't work

Comment: you could open it in iMovie and export it in another format..

Comment: I am sorry your comment made me realise, I am getting TV in options not iMovie. When I try to open in TV, nothing happens

Comment: What about photos app? And try uploading it to youtube. Or google drive, it might have some online converters(at risk of privacy). Use @ to ping me hereafter..

Comment: Have you tried opening it using Quicktime Player. Open the app first and then go to open menu item.

Comment: @jmh When trying to open the files via Quicktime, I can see the files, but they can't be selected. So can't open them

Comment: I was able to play the files in Windows Media player, if it help